# The existance of a cycle of length $n/2$ in a simple graph is NP-Complete

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

Definition:
A hamiltonian cycle is a cycle which crosses all of the vertices.

---

> Problem (i):   An arbitrary simple graph $G$ is given. Does $G$ have a
>   hamiltonian cycle?

---

Assume that we know problem (i) is NP-Complete.  How can we show that problem (ii) is NP-Complete, too?

> Problem (ii):  A simple graph $G$ is given. Does $G$ have a cycle of
>   length $n/2$?  ($n$ is the number of vertices)

---

Note 1: I know that i should use a reduction. But, The problem is that i don't know a way to translate the input of problem (ii) into an input of problem (i). Any idea?

Note 2: I want to learn a reduction. So, The thing that matters is the reduction, not just the answer of the question. **I want a translation function which takes a simple graph as input and returns another simple graph which can be seen as the input of problem (i).**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem (ii) is NP-complete even for graphs with $n/2$ isolated vertices. :-)

Comment: Why is this true? The point of this question is to learn about reductions... Can u please provide a translation function?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Given NP-hard problem (i), in order to show that Problem (ii)  is NP-hard too, the translation function should return the input of Problem (ii), not of Problem (i). See, assume that we have an “easy” algorithm $A$ solving Problem (ii). Then we can “easily” solve Problem (i) as follows. Given a simple graph $G$ we translate it to a graph $G’$ by adding $|V(G)|$ isolated vertices and then input $G’$ to $A$.

Comment: Then $A$ “easily” solves Problem (ii). But $G’$ has a cycle of  length $|V(G’)|/2$ iff $G$ has a cycle of length $|V(G)|$, so we have constructed an algorithm which “easily” solves NP-hard Problem (i), a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks ! That was great!